# How to debug spring boot maven project in debug mode in Intellij?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I run my maven project with the following command for dev profile from my terminal

```
 sudo mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

How can I run my project to run in debug mode with given profile. How to set configuration in intellij for this?

Answer (score 8):

Running a Spring Boot project from Maven with a specific profile

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo,bar
```

Or by using a shell variable

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=foo mvn spring-boot:run
```

Or by passing arguments to the JVM

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=foo,bar"
```

These are the only methods that I know of that work for Spring Boot v2.0+.
The first option is recognized by the Spring Boot Maven plugin and passes it on to the application JVM.
Since version 2.0 of Spring Boot, the `run` goal forks the process by default. Since `-Dspring.profiles.active` is not recognized by the plugin directly, it's only seen by the Maven process and not passed on to the app itself. This is why it doesn't work in the form `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=foo,bar`.
In the second option, the shell variable should be visible to any subprocesses spawned from that shell.

Starting a Spring Boot project in debug mode from Maven

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

Putting it together

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo,bar -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

Alternative, passing all arguments to JVM

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -Dspring.profiles.active=foo,bar"
```

The Maven `pom.xml` should include the Spring Boot plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</plugin>
```

In IntelliJ you should create a new "Remote" debug configuration from the "Run/Debug Configurations" tool window. You'll find it in the main menu - "Run / Edit Configurations..."
The default config will use the same `5005` port.
After that, launch that debug config. The console should display "Connected to the target VM...".

Sources:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html

Answer (score 3):

If you're running from maven, then add the following parameters:

```
 mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5555"
```

Here 5555 is a debug port number (you can use any other unoccupied port).

Then in IntelliJ you can use Remote Debug configuration and connect to that port.

If you open the pom.xml from intelliJ, you can create a Run Configuration with `--spring.profiles.active=dev` and main class that is a class with method main just like in a regular the most simple java application.

Comment: -Drun.jvmArguments doesn't seem to work with this plugin, "-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=" does.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Just click run button (green triable button) then click Debug...

IntelliJ will run your spring-boot app in debugging mode

If you want to run with arguments just open edit configuration and put your args in VM Options/Program arguments like

[image]

Comment: Starting in Spring Boot 2.2 add -Dspring-boot.run.profiles= also to specify profile